# LEGO sticky after painting?

Tags: plastics

Why are my LEGO still sticky after I paint them?  I use primer beforehand but the acrylic paint is still tacky hours after they're painted.  Thanks!

Comment: <MandatoryPuristRant />

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you used an acrylic paint with a solvent that softens ABS plastic.

Your bricks may take quite some time to harden.

It's possible they never will.

Comment: I sanded the brick and used primer but it's still sticky even though it's been drying for 3 hours so not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Sticky paint is usually caused by painting over a coat that wasn't fully dry. If you did not wait several hours after applying primer, that would be the cause.

Comment: I sanded the brick and used primer but it's still sticky even though it's been drying for 3 hours so not sure what I'm doing wrong?